The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead
I get these errors:
Error: Cannot find module 'expo-crypto'

The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.

This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "stickersmash",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "~3.2.1",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.91.8",
    "@web3auth/react-native-sdk": "^6.0.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.3.0",
    "expo": "~51.0.8",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.14",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false,
    "stream": false
  },
  "private": true
}

I have tried to add browser after devDependencies, and tried downgrade, but somehow it still doesn't work.
Did I miss anything?
